# How to write test class with invocable with multiple variable

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am looking at the solution on how to call the invocable method with different data points
[How invocable method and bulk behavior in Process Builder work?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107345/how-invocable-method-and-bulk-behavior-in-process-builder-work)
I am calling this invocable method from Process builder

But I do I write test class?

Comment: Hi Uma, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. The format here is to ask *specific* questions about a solution you have tried to implement and where you are stuck. Trying to solve the problem yourself is a vital first step in the process of getting value out of this site. The more research/development you do before posting, the better received your questions will be. Basic how to questions and broad requests for advice are a bad fit for this forum and are often perceived negatively, downvoted and/or closed as off topic.

Answer (score 2):

A great place to start would be:

- [Apex Developer Guide: InvocableMethod Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm)
- [Apex Developer Guide: InvocableVariable Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableVariable.htm)
- [Bob Buzzard Blog: Lightning Process Builder and Invocable Methods](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2015/02/lightning-process-builder-and-invocable.html)

Also, here's some simple examples:

- [Gist: SimpleEmailAction](https://gist.github.com/SalesforceBobLightning/e79eedb1e047d38583ce149a9a832ff8)
- [Gist: SystemDebugAction](https://gist.github.com/SalesforceBobLightning/ff6aeb442ec568df8a27d835c768fb53)

And this example has a test class:

- [Gist: UpdateFieldAction](https://gist.github.com/SalesforceBobLightning/d016b63af206bf0eaa724223366e784c)